# Deploy full Symfony2 app with composer

Tags: symfony, web-deployment, composer-php, symfony-2.3

Is there a way to setup a composer.json file in order to deploy a full Symfony 2.3 app?

Suppose I have the app in the git repo https://myrepo@bitbucket.org/myrepo/sfwebapp.git

Comment: Or you could use http://capifony.org/

Comment: I would also recommend http://capifony.org/ Some othert [deployment tools](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html)

Comment: Capifony seems excellent, but what if there is not ruby, but just PHP on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, composer is dependency manager, not deployment manager. Sure, you could:

1. Pull Git repo
2. Run composer --install (this is basically the essential step)
3. Warm up cache
4. Symlink resources
5. Install assets
6. ...
7. PROFIT

BUT, You would need to manually:

- Check/perform initial directory structure setup
- Keep track of old deployments
- ...

So, bottom line, *you could* achieve it but it would be like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You Can create directory structure in post-install-cmd scripts, but i agree that composer isn`t a way to go with deployment.